# How to merge two remote Git branches?

Tags: git, repository

I am setting up a remote repo that needs to house both a staging version of my code and a production version of the code (each branch will be deployed to their designated servers for testing / production).

I would like to only allow changes to be pushed from local machines to the remote staging branch, and then when we have decided that the staging branch is good to go, we could merge the staging branch into the production branch, and then deploy from there.

Basically, something like:

1. local.branch -> remote.staging
2. test on staging server
3. remote.staging -> remote.production
4. deploy remote.production

Is it possible to manage remote repos in this way? If so how?

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the (a) normal/supported workflow would be

1. local(staging).branch -> remote.staging
2. test on staging server
3. local(staging).branch -> local(production).branch
4. local(production).branch -> remote.production
5. deploy remote.production

Is that a scenario not possible for you?

Comment: its not bad, but if there are several workers working on the code...having them each push to the remote.staging once while they change is easy. once the staging is happy, itd be cool to just have one transition to remote.production rather than several. also, it seems safer to have a "vacuum sealed" remote.production that is never at risk of being uploaded to with weird stuff

Comment: It is not necessary for everyone to switch to the production branch. Only when someone wants to deploy production would she need to check it out. When she does, she simply pulls the latest changes from remote production, merges staging locally, pushes to remote production and is ready to deploy.